# Shutdown a remote computer connected in LAN in any preferable language

Tags: windows, language-agnostic

I want to shut down a remote Windows computer (ex. a Windows computer connected in LAN.) I have tried a lot but I could not find the solution. Does anyone have an idea on how to shut down the remote computer? Any language would work.

Comment: This isn't OS-agnostic.  If you're using Microsoft Windows, you've got answers already.  If you're using something else, you might want to specify it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming a windows box.

In VB.NET or c#

```
Process.Start("shutdown","-s -m \\Machine");
```

Should do the trick.

See
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx
http://www.ss64.com/nt/shutdown.html

EDIT: Note - `shutdown.exe` was only available in Resource Kits prior to Windows 2003

Comment: I believe that `shutdown.exe` was only available in Resource Kits prior to Windows 2003 (after which it is available in the default Windows installation).

Comment: @ephement: shutdown.exe is present on Windows XP.  It may also be present on Windows 2000.

Answer (score 5):

You can connect to any computer on the domain and shut it down using the [Win32Shutdown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394058.aspx) method of the WMI class Win32_OperatingSystem.  In .NET you access WMI through the [System.Management](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.aspx) namespace.

Answer (score 1):

Invoke *shutdown -s -m \\computername* command through a primitive used to start processes (like Process.Start() or CreateProcess()).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this code sample works, but it [illustrates how you can use WMI to remotely shutdown a computer.](http://www.csharpfriends.com/Forums/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=36953)

Answer (score 1):

If the remote computer is a Windows box you can use WMI (Windows Management Instrumentation).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582.aspx

Use the Reboot() method of the Win32_OperatingSystem class. You could do this for example using Windows Script, C#, VB .net

Answer (score 1):

1. Connect to the host through SSH
2. user@domain:~$ sudo shutdown -h now

Answer (score 0):

From a linux box [`net rpc shutdown`]

or call [initiateSystemShutdown](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=site%3Amsdn.microsoft.com%20initiateSystemShutdown)