# Program to remote shutdown multiple Windows computers within LAN c++

Tags: c++, windows, shutdown, lan

I trying to create a program to shut down computers within a LAN. I currently don't even know how to start.

Answer (score 1):

Did you Search in the internet. There are plenty of resources already to find.

`Process.Start("shutdown","-s -m \\Machine");`

more info :

- [Shutdown a remote computer connected in LAN in any preferable language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/685528/shutdown-a-remote-computer-connected-in-lan-in-any-preferable-language)
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22718/Shutdown-Remote-Using-Shutdown-exe
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376872%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Please avoid link-only answers. At least summarize the referenced pages.

Comment: actually, i tried this but it doesn't work. Do you have any configuration instruction of the target computer ?